# Scala convert Iterable or collection.Seq to collection.immutable.Seq

Tags: scala, scala-collections

It appears the `toSeq` method in Scala collections returns a `scala.collection.Seq`, I could also return a `Traversable` or `Iterable` but need to convert this to a `scala.collection.immutable.Seq`.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use the `to` method to convert between arbitrary collection types in Scala 2.10:

```
scala> Array(1, 2, 3).toSeq
res0: Seq[Int] = WrappedArray(1, 2, 3)

scala> Array(1, 2, 3).to[collection.immutable.Seq]
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Your answer helped me, but WHY, oh why is this even needed? I'm only working with immutable collections - how come a result of for-yield would need such a .to?

Comment: My friend, Ivan Yurchenko clarified this: The problem is that there are three things:
A) scala.collection.Seq
B) scala.collection.immutable.Seq
C) scala.collection.mutable.Seq

B and C derive from A so, if we have A, we can't surely say if it's mutable or immutable, that's why explicit conversion (.toList or something) or setting them immutable from the beginning is needed

Comment: It's just weird because the default Seq in Scala is just collections.Seq; which is odd because mostly, everything is immutable.  List(1,2,3).toSeq generates a collections.Seq... not immutable.collections.Seq.  Doesn't that seem wrong?

Comment: and even more weirdly - a immutable.collections.Seq .toIterable yields a collections.Iterable, NOT a immutable.collections.Iterable!